# How to transform json using underscore js

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, underscore.js, amazon-athena

I am calling Athena Rest API and in response I am getting JSON mention below. There can be more "Data" elements but the first "Data" element will always contain the keys and the rest of the " Data" elements will contain the values as mention in below payLoad

```
 {
      "ResultSet": {
        "Rows": [
          {
            "Data": [
              {
                "VarCharValue": "date"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "location"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "browser"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "uri"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "status"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Data": [
              {
                "VarCharValue": "2014-07-05"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "SFO4"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "Safari"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "200"
              }
            ]
          },
{
            "Data": [
              {
                "VarCharValue": "2014-07-05"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "SFO4"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "opera"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
              },
              {
                "VarCharValue": "300"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "UpdateCount": 0
    }
```

What I need to do is to tranform this object into the below mention JSON. Can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 [ 
      {     
          "date": "2014-07-05"     
          "location": "SFO4"
          "browser": "Safari"
          "uri": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
          "status": "200"                
       },
      {     
          "date": "2014-07-05"     
          "location": "SFO4"
          "browser": "opera"
          "uri": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
          "status": "300"                
       }
 ]
```

Comment: Will there only ever be two `Data` elements? If there can be more, please show an input & output example.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi John there can be more "Data" elements but the first "Data" element will always contain the keys and the rest of the " Data" elements will contain the values. I have edited the question with multiple Data elements

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the desired result with this

```
var rows = response.ResultSet.Rows;

// Get columns name (first row).
var columnsName = _.pluck(rows[0].Data, 'VarCharValue');

return _.map(_.rest(rows, 1), function(row) {
    return _.object(columnsName, _.pluck(row.Data, 'VarCharValue'));
});
```